# How to solve a floor equation?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to solve the following equation, but I've found some difficulties.

$$\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt[3] x\rfloor\quad\quad(x\in \mathbb R)$$

Comment: What is E in this case?

Comment: I assume it's floor function from the title?

Comment: instead to write  [x] I 've wrote E(x) but it s the same thing

Comment: @wuppertal so far, $0$ and $1$ are the only legitimate solutions for me...

Comment: What kind of difficulties did you have?

Comment: thank you so much for you 're particpation but dplease could you give how do you found the solution cause i didn't understand

Comment: All values of x belongs to this interval $ 0 \leq x < 4 $ are solution.

Comment: It is better to write
$\large\left\lfloor y^{3}\right\rfloor
 =
 \left\lfloor y\right\rfloor$.

Comment: @DanielY I fail to understand your comment. What about `x=2`? (To keep things simple.)

Comment: I don't have any ideas about the methode that could help

Comment: to solve this kind of floor inequation

Comment: @Did, as I said in my comment ("so far"), that's a partial answer...Eventually mama got it write...way to go!

Comment: ok but how you could found those inervalles

Comment: tell me you're methode

Answer (score 3):

If $x\lt0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is undefined hence the question makes no sense. For every $x$ in $[0,1)$, $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt[3]{x}$ are both in $[0,1)$ hence $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt[3]{x}\rfloor=0$.

If $x\gt1$, $\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor=\lfloor\sqrt[3]{x}\rfloor$ if and only if there exists an integer $n$ such that $n\leqslant\sqrt[3]{x}\leqslant\sqrt{x}\lt n+1$. Since $x\gt1$, one knows that $n\geqslant1$. The double inequality is equivalent to $n^3\leqslant x\lt(n+1)^2$, in particular one must have $n^3\lt(n+1)^2$. For $n\geqslant1$, this means that $n=1$ or $n=2$. Thus, every $x$ such that $1^3\leqslant x\lt(1+1)^2$ or $2^3\leqslant x\lt(2+1)^2$ is a solution.

Finally, the set of solutions is $[0,4)\cup[8,9)$.

Comment: thank you so much that's what i was searching for . :)

Comment: You are welcome. But next time, please insert your thoughts on the question you ask. "I've found some difficulties" is definitely not informative enough.

Comment: $\large\left\lfloor 0.5\right\rfloor = 0 \not= 1$.

Comment: @FelixMarin That is true. And?

Comment: @Did, you had a $1$ that was supposed to be a $0$. I fixed it. It did not infect anything else.

Comment: @dfeuer Oops, me stoopid. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks for pointing the typo.